# Angular 6 client for C# Grpc server - getting error in nodeHttp.js

Tags: c#, angular6, grpc

[Getting http/https module load error in nodeHttp.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRS7L.jpg)

Here, I am trying to develop Angular 6 client for C# gRPC server. I had created .ts and .js files by using protoc compiler and ts related plugin ts-protoc-gen.

When i try to build the Angular application i am getting the above error.

Comment: The code is looking for the Angular source code on the D: drive. You probably have it installed in a different folder.You need to modify your configuration to look for the Angular in the correct location.Often issues like this you code didn't recompile when it was installed.So I often recommend making a copy of the project bin folder and then deleting the bin folder and compile.You should always add a reference project by using Add existing item and then browsing for the executable in the existing project.When you compile a project the reference projects executable is copied to the bin folder.

Comment: I had installed all the node modules in the same application folder. I'm getting issue in grpc-web-client plugin.

Comment: @jdweng You should put that as an answer, even if it isn't solving Tamil's particular problem it might help someone else !

Comment: How did you do the installation?  Either something is not installed properly in the grpc code or it needs to be compiled.

Comment: I had installed grpc in the application folder by using the command "npm install grpc --save", installed grpc-web-client using the command "npm install google-protobuf @types/google-protobuf grpc-web-client --save", and installed Typescript protocol buffer compiler using the command "npm install ts-protoc-gen". All the commands are executed by using NodeJS command prompt.I had referred the link https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/tree/master/ts to work with .ts file in the client side. I had followed the same in Angular 6 application.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with improbable's grpc-web code generator, but I am familiar with using the official grpc-web tools. Hopefully the process I describe below may still be helpful:

Typically you would want to generate a .js file that contains all the proto message definitions along with the grpc-web client. In my project, I do this in a script: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-experiments/blob/master/grpc-zpages/buildscripts/channelz_codgen.sh, which calls this script inside of the grpc-web docker: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-experiments/blob/master/grpc-zpages/docker/codegen/shared_dir/scripts/gen_channelz_pb.sh

The result is a standalone .js file.

Then you can either import the js file in your HTML file via a `<script src="..."/>` tag before your `<app-root></app-root>`, or make angular import the script during compilation like I am doing here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-experiments/pull/306

You can find more info about how to use scripts with angular here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Answer (score 0):

The grpc-web nodeHttps transport depends upon node-internal packages: http, https, url. These were removed from Angular 6, which causes attempting to build an Angular6 application using grpc-web-client fails.

https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/issues/191

Because you won't be using the nodeHttps transport (it's for Node applications using grpc-web, and there's a native implementation of grpc for Node, so grpc-web isn't necessary) you can override these modules in your tsconfig.json to point to an empty file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "https": [ "src/app/patch.js" ],
      "http": [ "src/app/patch.js" ],
      "url": [ "src/app/patch.js" ],
  }
}
```

where src/app/patch.js is an empty file (or one referencing the relevant issue):

```
//https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/issues/191
```